# Launching Server.exe from User Data on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use EC2 UserData to launch the .exe of my asp.net core 3 server.  This way the server runs on launch of the instance.  I know most servers don't launch this way, but mine does some weird stuff so it has to run as an .exe on Windows.

The UserData script runs and does write out the date & time.  Moreover, the UserdataExecution.log shows all the desired commands being executed.  Finally, running those commands in the command prompt works and the .exe starts and keeps running.  The path to the .exe is valid.

However, when I go into the instance and check, the .exe isn't running.  I have no idea why it isn't, especially since it says that it ran the command.

My only thought is that, since it ran on start, there are rules on not launching exes that spin?  However, I haven't found any examples/documentation of this. Is that the case?  If so, is there another way of doing this?

This is what my logs say is being executed:

C:\Windows\system32>echo Current date and time, as a test:  1>>C:\Windows\Temp\test.log

C:\Windows\system32>echo Tue 10/29/2019 22:27:16.17  1>>C:\Windows\Temp\test.log

C:\Windows\system32>START "Coordinator" "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\uvue\src\api\Coordinator\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Coordinator.exe"

Comment: Why don't you add your exe to be started by windows itself on machine restart. Later you can bake it into an AMI

Comment: @Juned Ahsan As far as I can tell, this only happens on a user login.  When I launch the EC2 instance it doesn't actually launch the exe until I RDP in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Start command with /B option,like

START "Coordinator" /B "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\uvue\src\api\Coordinator\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Coordinator.exe"

Comment: Thank you kind sir!